# Freestyle line thickness based on lighting?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, freestyle

Is it possible to have a freestyle line render thin where the underlying geometry gets a lot of direct light and thick where it's not getting any direct light? I'm using a single light source in the scene.

I've distant memories that there was a setting for this in 3DSMax a long time ago when I first experimented with cartoon outline style before coming to Blender so I assumed now, many years later, there would be something similar in Blender. There doesn't seem to be anything to control this directly. I wonder if it can be done somehow.